# Vue add existing Firebase ID for "relation"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2, vuefire

I am using Vue and Firebase via VueFire to build a form to relate objects. I have the following form and method:

```
<form @submit.prevent="addRelation">
      <select v-model="newRelation.parent">
        <option v-for="item in content">{{item.name}}</option>
      </select>
      <select v-model="newRelation.child">
        <option v-for="item in content">{{item.name}}</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Add Relation"/>
    </form>
```

And Vue:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        related: {},
        newRelation: {
            parent: '',
            child: ''
        }
    },
    firebase: {
        content: contentRef,
        related: relatedRef
    },
    methods: {
        addRelation() {
            relatedRef.push(this.newRelation)
            console.log('relation added')
        }
    },
```

This adds JSON like so in Firebase:

```
{
    "child": "objectc",
    "parent": "objecta",
    ".key": "-KjFYZn8dqP29uLmJBJP"
  },
```

It pushes a new Firebase ID and nests the data. In order for Firebase to handle 'relationships' correctly they must be structured like so:

```
{
    ".key":"-Existing ID of object A
    "-Existing ID of object B": true
}
```

How can I update my method to structure info like so? I have this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/VbzrzE?editors=0011) The bottom two entries in the "'Related' Content" section show how I want it to submit (I added manually).